# find in List of Maps in DART

Tags: dart

I have a List of maps like this

```
"reportFields": [
        {
            "id": "opcode",
            "displayId": "Code",
            "dataType": "list",
        },
        {
            "id": "cat",
            "displayId": "Category",
            "dataType": "list",
          },
        {
            "id": "label",
            "displayId": "Signature",
            "dataType": "list",

        }
];
```

how to find index of the map which has the value "label" as "id" ?

Answer (score 0):

You might do something like that :

```
  final data = {"reportFields": [
    {
      "id": "opcode",
      "displayId": "Code",
      "dataType": "list",
    },
    {
      "id": "cat",
      "displayId": "Category",
      "dataType": "list",
    },
    {
      "id": "label",
      "displayId": "Signature",
      "dataType": "list",

    }
  ]};

  print(data['reportFields'].where((f) => f['id'] == 'label'));
```

result :

```
({id: label, displayId: Signature, dataType: list})
```